# What are better Java web application frameworks (Suggestions please)?

Tags: java, jsf, web-frameworks, jsf-2

I am new to Java Web Application. I am practicing with JSF2. 
Is it better to use any framework with JSF or just should I move with JSF?

If it is better to use Framework, what you experienced guys suggest me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most up-to-date way to write Java web applications and web-based front-end ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703656/what-is-the-most-up-to-date-way-to-write-java-web-applications-and-web-based-fron)

Comment: May be, I searched for and got many result. But I am ambiguous that how JSF support available with them.

Comment: Please ask more clear and precise questions. Is it if you want to choose between JSF1.x and JSF2? If you're building an application from scratch then you should definitely use JSF2. If the question is which web application framework you should use in general, then there is no real answer. It just depends on your needs and your personal preferences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Framework Choice Question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062188/java-framework-choice-question), [Struts 2 or JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845271/struts-2-or-jsf), [Choosing a Java web framework now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now)

Comment: btw, when choosing a framework, we have to consider about Documentation, Guides, Backing/User Community and etc... This will not only help learning the technology quickly, will help in future development also. In the aspect of those supports, any one has any comparison between SpringWebFow,Wicket, Playframwork,Grail, Google webkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no best solution or framework. You'd better define, even for yourself, what exactly you want the application to do and then seek the most appropriate technology. Not to be too abstract, I'd suggest you check out Struts, Spring and GWT(Google Web Toolkit).

Each of them has its pros and cons, so it's not a matter of becoming guru in just one of them, but better knowing them all well in order to make a good decision, when one is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try [**Play! Framework**](http://www.playframework.org/). It seems to be a nice RAD framework especially for simple apps.

Comment: +1 for Play. Combine it with lots of jQuery goodness and it's hard to beat.

Comment: +1 for Play, it's unique in java world (like django of java). I think it'll rule the java world in the following years.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) is quite nice. But then again, I don't particularly like JSPs.

Just have a look at their [motivation](http://wicket.apache.org/introduction.html) page to see what sets them apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot frameworks to simplify framework usage and boost efficience.

I would prefer **[Spring Webflow](http://www.springsource.org/go-webflow2)**. It handles conversational state, is simple to use and you can take profit of the other features spring offers (IoC/Dependency Injection, Integration features, Spring Batch ...)

When you have the freedom to use different languages/apis you should have a look at **[Grails](http://www.grails.org/)**.

Comment: Is Grails is part of Spring or is it completely different one?

Comment: I simply went through the page of Grails. Features are looking smarter.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your needs. Personally I prefer Spring+Struts2+Hibernate or grails.

Comment: Yes its an ORM, but if you think of adding a persistence layer to your app you need to use something therefore I consider sptring+struts2+hibernate as web app "frameworks combo" ;)

Comment: What is actually struts? Hibernate is ORM, Spring is webframework. Sturts2?? Something between?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the [Seam Framework](http://seamframework.org) from JBoss.  It helps simplify JSF quite a bit, and also makes it very easy to integrate things like Hibernate or EJB3.  Plus, it's quite pretty wide support across the major IDEs.

Comment: Opening link... Wow,, I can see some best features in Seam Framework ... ""Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX), JavaServer Faces (JSF), Java Persistence (JPA), Enterprise Java Beans (EJB 3.0) and Business Process Management (BPM) "" I will do a comparison anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/ which is powerful than JSF

Comment: Your wording is confusing. IceFaces **is** a JSF component library.